# Having trouble compressing a file in a different directory

Tags: linux, bash, copy, cp

Okay so essentially what I'm doing, is I'm taking all the directories inside of the /servers/ folder, and moving them to a secondary hard drive mounted at /media/backupdrive/.  This script is ran once a day, so it makes the directory with the name of the date, and should copy the folders directly over there (The reason I have to do it this way is because my client has limited disk space on his main hard drive and his worlds are upwards of 6-7gb each).  Anyway, I can get them to copy the folders to /media/backupdrive/currentdate, but then when I try to compress it, it says it can't compress an empty directory or something along the lines of that.

Here's the code:

```
#!bin/bash
folderName=$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
mkdir "/media/backupdrive/$folderName"

for i in servers/*; do
    cp -rf $i /media/backupdrive/$folderName/
    cd /media/backupdrive/$folderName/
    tar -C ${i:8} -czvf "${i:8}.tar.gz"
    cd /root/multicraft/
done
```

Sorry for the image, it was on a virtual machine and I had to re-type it, because I couldn't copy and paste.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but how exactly is `cp -rf servers/${i:8}/ ...` supposed to work? You're saying that for each subdirectory of ` servers` you want to copy a subdirectory whose name is a substring of the original name (starting with the 8th character).

Comment: I was just testing.  servers/${i:8}/ is the same as just $i.  I just noticed that. I used ${i:8} when it came to just getting the name of the directory (would cut off servers/)

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like your tar command is missing its input (e.g., a final "."), and therefore says, "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive".

Your script appears to work for me with this tar command:

```
tar -C ${i#servers/} -czvf "${i#servers/}.tar.gz" .
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a slightly different approach. `tar` by itself doesn't use temporary files, so you could `tar` the sources directly to the destination and compress them wizh `gzip` in a second step.

```
#!bin/bash

dst="/media/backupdrive/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")"

for d in servers/*; do
  tarfile="$dst/${d#servers/}.tar"
  tar -C "$d" -cvf "$tarfile" .
  gzip -9 "$tarfile"
done
```